# wpf richtextbox data loading completion event/method

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

Is there any event get fired upon completion of data loading into richtextbox...

can't use text_changed as it called every time any single alphabet/number/symbol loaded... just looking for some help for some event to be called upon completion of data.

Comment: How you are loading the data into the `RichTextBox` should give you the idea on when it is done.

Comment: Just call the event from the get

Comment: i m not loading, some third party is loading.. i have access to its contents